# Multiple names for JSON field

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, json-deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

I use [`kotlinx.serialization`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library to serialize/deserialize JSONs. There is a JSON string:

```
{"id":"1"}
```

that can be also represented as

```
{"uid":"1"}
```

And I want to handle both names with one property, e.g.:

```
@Serializable
data class User(val id: String)
```

Is it possible to parse both JSONs using only one `data` class and its property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `@JsonNames` annotation to provide alternative names in addition to the name of the property (see [doc](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#alternative-json-names)). You can also define more than one additional name in the annotation.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializable
data class User(
    @JsonNames("uid")
    val id: String,
)
```

For *serialization*, the property name will be used. For *deserialization*, the JSON may contain either the property name or the additional name, both are mapped to the `id` property.